# Using iterator in ModelBuilder with layers in REST Service

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, iterator, rest

Is it possible to get an iterator in ModelBuilder to iterate through layers in a REST service?

It appears to be possible to extract data from many REST service layers. However, I want to point an iterator at a list of REST service layers and extract data based on other conditions outlined in the Model (proximity, selection, etc.). I know it is possible to point an iterator at a geodatabase or workspace but I have not been able to point one at specific layers on a server.

Here's an example of some of the rest service links I want to use:
https://maps.gov.bc.ca/arcgis/rest/services/mpcm/bcgwpub/MapServer/39
https://maps.gov.bc.ca/arcgis/rest/services/mpcm/bcgwpub/MapServer/512
https://maps-cartes.ec.gc.ca/arcgis/rest/services/BC_CriticalHabitat_CB_HabitatEssentiel/MapServer

Comment: Are you able to provide a URL to a test REST service?  Doing that may entice a potential answerer to try and test to see where you are stuck.

Comment: Both URLs that you have provided give:
ArcGIS REST Framework
Home 
Error: Services Directory has been disabled.
Code: 403 so it looks like it is password protected.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box iterator to loop over a Map or FeatureService like a workspace.
You can however fake it using the **For** iterator. But you need to set it up in a very specific way and need to have a lot of prior knowledge of the service when constructing it. (Alternatively you can make a tool and expose the parameters. Whoever is uing this tool would then add the information at run time based on a given service).

See the below image on how I've constructed it, the explanation is as follows:

The featureservice I'm passing in has 3 layers in it. I setup FOR with a **From Value =0**, **To Value =2** and **By Value =1** (as Services are 0-indexed). So it'll loop 0, 1, 2 to get all 3 layers. Note - this MapService variable is simply a pre-condition to the iterator. The connection is not required.

From there I use *Calculate Value* to basically do a string merge. That's mashing up the full URL (ending with a trailing slash / ) with the layer index (0,1,2). As I've set my output to a Feature Class, the next tool accepts it.

*Copy Features* takes this input, as it's a tool that will interact with a service layer URL. (Remember, not all tools will take service layer URLs like this). I then use the %Value% variable to keep the final output names unique (fullurl_copyfeatures_0,1,2)

This is the start to what you're asking. Once you have it as a copied feature to your disk, you're in a good situation to clip/extract/whatever you want with this data based on your needed workflow.

[image]